# IIS Express error when running from VS 2019 Community Edition

Tags: express, iis

When I tried to run my code through IIS10 Express I now get a strange error screen.

[image: screenshot]

It has been working fine up until a few days ago. It also works fine if I use VS 2022 but that runs like a snail on my laptop so I'd like to stick with 2019. I've tried various VS website projects and they all fail.

Anyone have any ideas as I've tried "googling" for a clue but all I find out there are IIS7 suggestions and some of the commands they use no longer exist (or aren't installed in my OS!)

Answer (score 0):

> HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error
>
> An error message detailing
> the cause of this specific request failure can be found in the
> application event log of the web server. Please review this log entry
> to discover what caused this error to occur.

It is difficult to reproduce your problem according to your description, you need more detailed error information to analyze and solve the problem.

Error code 0x80131704 means: "A different runtime was already bound to the legacy CLR version 2 activation policy". It refers to a conflict with the runtime version IIS using to execute the application. Either web.config or another config file is instructing IIS to run the application on a .NET framework version that is not compatible with the version the application is targeting.

As the error message indicates, you need to check the application event log, or you can try using [FRT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis) to view details about the 500 error, which will generate a detailed log file to help you identify the problem.

This link may be of some help to you: [AspNetInitClrHostFailureModule error with 0x80131704 error code](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/aspnetinitclrhostfailuremodule-0x80131704-2148734724/ba-p/1839824)

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I discovered my Windows 10 install had been corrupted so I had to rebuild my laptop. I upgraded to VS2022 as well.